# Python modules not working after macOS Catalina update

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-import, python-module, macos-catalina

After updating macOS to Catalina, I can no longer import modules like Pandas, Numpy or Scipy--I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Interestingly, `import os` and `import sys` do *not* throw this error.

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably after update you have another default Python interpreter.

You either should find where "the old one" is located or install again all libraries needed (e.g. `pip install pandas`)

Comment: Did not work, unfortunately. I already had these modules installed but tried running `pip install pandas` as you suggested anyway, but it still didn't work. Somehow Python is not accessing the installed libraries. It might have something to do with a new version of Python I installed too. Is there a way to "wipe the slate clean" by completely uninstalling all Python versions and then installing a new one? I use Anaconda as my package manager.

Comment: try to handle it via the [virtualenv](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)